# What logs can I use to diagnose connectivity issues on a GCE network?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-logging, google-vpc

On Google Cloud we are using the following:

- A Cloud Function that connects to
- A service running on a GCE VM
- via a VPC Access Connector

Its been running fine for months then all of a sudden it stopped working and all attempts to connect to the service cause the following error in our Cloud Function logs:

> Connection to 10.X.X.X timed out. (connect timeout=10)

That IP address is the IP address of the VM.

At this point I'm not sure how to go about diagnosing the problem as GCE networking is unfamiliar to me. What should I be searching for in Cloud Logging to try and determine the root cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that much more detailed logs are available by filtering on

`resource.type="gce_subnetwork"`

These logs provide much more detailed information about the network traffic.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Cloud Logging to check the logs of your GCE Networking. You check it on:

1. Navigation Menu > Logging > Log Explorer
2. On the right upper part of your GCP console, click **Resource**.
3. Scroll down and choose **GCE Network**.
4. Once you click GCE Network, it will show you the Network ID of your VPC network
5. Then choose where your VM instance is located then click “apply”.

For more information about Cloud Logging you can explore this [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface).

Comment: Thank you. I've looked at the logs for the last 7 days and every single log record has 'protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.networks.get"' which don't tell me very much. I was hoping I could find much more detailed logs about traffic on the network and, more importantly, information about why I am seeing connection failures in my Cloud Function logs. Do I need to enable something to capture more detailed logs?

Comment: Youre welcome. Regarding for the detailed network logs I can also suggest to enable “Flow Logs” you can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-flow-logs) on how to enable your flow logs. Once flow logs is enable you can follow the steps below:

1. Go to VPC Network.
2. Click the subnet that you are using.
3. Click “View Flow Logs”

Make sure that there are traffic flowing in your network to log network traffic. If you want to know more about VPC Flow Logs, you can also check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/flow-logs)